# Lost my openshift console ("Application is not available")

Tags: oauth, openshift

The console ui in my OpenShift 4.5.x installation has mysteriously stopped working. Visiting the console URL now results in the message:

> Application is not available
>
> The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.

One usually sees this if a route exists but is cannot find a corresponding service or pod, but in this case, the route exists:

```
$ oc -n openshift-console get route
NAME        HOST/PORT                                             PATH   SERVICES    PORT    TERMINATION          WILDCARD
console     console-openshift-console.apps.example.com            console     https   reencrypt/Redirect   None
downloads   downloads-openshift-console.apps.example.com          downloads   http    edge/Redirect        None
```

The service exists:

```
$ oc -n openshift-console get service
NAME        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
console     ClusterIP   172.30.36.70     <none>        443/TCP   57d
downloads   ClusterIP   172.30.190.186   <none>        80/TCP    57d
```

And the pods exist and are healthy:

```
$ oc -n openshift-console get pods
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
console-76c8d7d755-gtfm8   0/1     Running   1          4m12s
console-76c8d7d755-mvf6n   0/1     Running   1          4m12s
downloads-9656c996-mmqhk   1/1     Running   0          53d
downloads-9656c996-z2khj   1/1     Running   0          53d
```

Looking at the logs for the console pods, there appears to be a problem contacting the oauth service:

```
2021-01-04T22:05:48Z auth: error contacting auth provider (retrying in 10s): Get https://kubernetes.default.svc/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2021-01-04T22:05:58Z auth: error contacting auth provider (retrying in 10s): request to OAuth issuer endpoint https://oauth-openshift.apps.example.com/oauth/token failed: Head https://oauth-openshift.apps.example.com: EOF
2021-01-04T22:06:13Z auth: error contacting auth provider (retrying in 10s): request to OAuth issuer endpoint https://oauth-openshift.apps.example.com/oauth/token failed: Head https://oauth-openshift.apps.example.com: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2021-01-04T22:06:23Z auth: error contacting auth provider (retrying in 10s): request to OAuth issuer endpoint https://oauth-openshift.apps.example.com/oauth/token failed: Head https://oauth-openshift.apps.example.com: EOF
2021-01-04T22:06:38Z auth: error contacting auth provider (retrying in 10s): request to OAuth issuer endpoint https://oauth-openshift.apps.example.com/oauth/token failed: Head https://oauth-openshift.apps.example.com: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2021-01-04T22:06:53Z auth: error contacting auth provider (retrying in 10s): request to OAuth issuer endpoint https://oauth-openshift.apps.example.com/oauth/token failed: Head https://oauth-openshift.apps.example.com: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

But the pods in the `openshift-authentication` namespace appear to be healthy and are not reporting any errors in the logs. Where should I be looking for the source of the problem?

---

The expected route and service exist in the `openshift-authentication` namespace:

```
$ oc -n openshift-authentication get route
NAME              HOST/PORT                                 PATH   SERVICES          PORT   TERMINATION            WILDCARD
oauth-openshift   oauth-openshift.apps.example.com          oauth-openshift   6443   passthrough/Redirect   None

$ oc -n openshift-authentication get service
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
oauth-openshift   ClusterIP   172.30.233.202   <none>        443/TCP   57d

$ oc -n openshift-authentication get route oauth-openshift -o json | jq .status
{
  "ingress": [
    {
      "conditions": [
        {
          "lastTransitionTime": "2020-11-08T19:48:08Z",
          "status": "True",
          "type": "Admitted"
        }
      ],
      "host": "oauth-openshift.apps.example.com",
      "routerCanonicalHostname": "apps.example.com",
      "routerName": "default",
      "wildcardPolicy": "None"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: So it looks like your OAuth issuer endpoint is not working as expected. Does the Route  `https://oauth-openshift.apps.example.com` exist in your cluster? Does the Service exist? Can you add that output to your question?

Comment: @simon I've updated the question; the service and route exist and look fine from what I can tell.

Comment: Thanks, so far so good. Check if you can reach "https://oauth-openshift.apps.example.com/oauth/token" from the outside (using `curl` or similar). If that is the case, maybe the Console Pods are using some kind of proxy to connect to that endpoint? Hard to say.

Comment: Trying to `curl` the url from outside the cluster results in `curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to oauth-openshift.apps.example.com:443`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with the default ingress routers. There were no obvious errors, but I was able to resolve the problem by restarting the routers:

```
oc -n openshift-ingress get pod -o json |
  jq -r '.items[].metadata.name' |
  xargs oc -n openshift-ingress delete pod
```

Answer (score 1):

i had same issue on OpenShift 3.11

i just deleted secret with certificate, openshift will create new secret, now console works.

```
oc delete secret console-serving-cert -n openshift-console
```

Comment: can you elaborate on this? will certificates related be renewed? it did not work for me.